# CSS: Referencing Nested Element Without Class or ID

Tags: html, css, nested

I am new to CSS/HTML and have a question regarding nesting (one I think many others might encounter as they are new to CSS). I have the following code:

```
<article id="rightarticle">
     <h2 id="sightings">Cougar Sightings Increase <img src="cougar.jpg" alt="BEWARE"/></h2>
```

The **h2** element is not the only **h2** element under the **article** subsection; however, it is the first. My goal is to target *only* the first **h2** element to change its background.

Without using the #sightings reference - i.e. the id - how do I reference only the first h2 element of the article element in CSS? Accepting symantic conventions, that article is the largest element, I am assuming I could not use a first-child reference to isolate *only* the element above?

Comment: Use `:first-of-type`.

Comment: Actually, I just changed the code - making the `:first-child` pseudo-element possible (I just realized the code was bad - missing a section). The `:first-child` would - I believe - in the above case select each child of type `<h2>`, not isolating the first, therefore requiring @Vucko 's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `>` child selector and `:first-of-type` psuedo class selector.

Select by `#rightarticle` ID:

```
#rightarticle > h2:first-of-type {}
```

Select by `<article>` tag:

```
article > h2:first-of-type {}
```

Comment: Thanks! Still learning the nuances (and the textbook I have is terrible).